# How to add metainfo to xtext generated file

Tags: java, xtext

I want to write some metainfo to generated java file from xtext, eg author or similar as comment or constant.

The best would be to read a system variable, where I can put my info, eg git sha1, author....

How can this be made ?

Comment: am not sure to which files you referring to but did you check the fileHeader option as the workflow created by the wizard has it?

Comment: Please, do you have an example ?

Comment: https://github.com/itemis/xtext-reference-projects/blob/dc3bf74b7769e60ec3a2f6b9f91e5807160e477c/greetings-tycho/2.23.0/org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2#L29